# How do I reverse a EJS forEach loop

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, loops, ejs

Below is my ejs code, pulling from my database, how would I go about getting my array to display my array of images and names in reversed order ?

```
<% posts.forEach(function(post){ %>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                   <img src="<%= post.image %>">
                   <div class="caption">
                       <h4><%= post.name %></h4>
                   </div>
                   <p>
                       <a href="/posts/<%= post._id %>" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
                   </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% }); %>
```

Comment: what about a normal `for(i=post.length; i >= 0; i--)` ?

Comment: Related: [Loop through array backwards with forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682962/javascript-angular-loop-through-array-backwards-with-foreach)

Comment: @416seller, why is there no accepted answer yet? Didn't it work?

Answer (score 4):

You could do `posts.reverse().forEach(...` to archieve that.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to [copy the array first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript), since `.reverse()` will modify `posts` directly before returning it. Otherwise, might be surprised later if `posts` is iterated over again.

Answer (score -1):

If Some beginner like me is looking at this question in 2021 or later. You can use the for loop to show the posts array in reverse order. In this case, the above code can be modified in the following way to show it in reverse.

```
<% for(var i= (posts.length-1); i>=0; i--){ %>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="<%= posts[i].image %>">
    <div class="caption">
      <h4><%= posts[i].name %></h4>
    </div>
    <p>
      <a href="/posts/<%= posts[i]._id %>" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<% } %>
```