# How do I loop through an array in reactjs, but starting with the last element?

Tags: reactjs

Currently, am looping through an Array with the following code:

`{allThrows.map((handThrow, index) => {`

But this starts with `index=0`; how can I start and work down to 0 from `allThrows.length-1` as the first element and decrement by 1 from there?

Comment: Here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682962/javascript-loop-through-array-backwards-with-foreach

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - Loop through array backwards with forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682962/javascript-loop-through-array-backwards-with-foreach)

Comment: Use a for loop.

Comment: @TR3 it is one way, I found the below answer with reverse() helpful and cleaner given I am already  using map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's 2 way:

-`reverse()`

you can reverse your array first then loop through it by `allThrows.reverse().map()`, and have in mind, this will reverse the original array. you can store it in a new variable first.

-`reduceRight()`

this method applies a function on `currentValue` and send the result (`accumulator`) to next step, backwards.
but you can ignore the passed result and use only `currentValue`.
like this:

```
allThrows.reduceRight((accumulator,currentValue)=>{ 
console.log(currentValue)
return null
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
[...allThrows].reverse().map((handThrow, index) => { //do something in reverse }
```

if you don't care about the index but just about mapping the array items in reverse